# Draw bone for skinned mesh

Tags: opengl, skeletal-animation, skeletal-mesh

I have the JointTransform matrix for each bones of each frame in the animation of a simple rigged model. I would like to draw the bones as lines. I'm using OpenGl 2. I just want to calculate the start and end Vector3 points. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether your matrices are in world or local space, whether you are storing the joints as a tree (or a flattened array with indexing), and whether you are using push/pop or your own matrix maths.

If you are storing the joints in a hierarchy, and the data is local space, you will need to recurse to render the character:

```cpp
void recurseHierarahcy(Joint* p)
    glPushMatrix();
    glMultMatrix(p->localTransform);
    for(int i = 0; i < p->numChildren; ++i) {
       Joint* child = p->getCHild(i);
       glBegin(GL_LINES);
         // the line starts at the origin of the parent frame...
         glVertex3f(0,0,0);

         // and extends to the translation of the child (in local space)
         glVertex3f(child->localTransform[12], 
                    child->localTransform[13], 
                    child->localTransform[14]);
       glEnd();
       recurseHierarahcy(child);
    }
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

If you have world space matrices, then you just need to join the dots between the world space transforms... (I'm assuming these transforms are in world space, and you've stored the character in an array!)

```cpp
void drawJointLines(Joint* joints, int count)
   glBegin(GL_LINES);
   for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i ){
       Joint* joint = joints + I;

       // only draw lines for joints that have parents.
       if(joint->hasParent()) {
           Joint* parent = joint->getParent();

           // the line extends between the parent and the child.
           glVertex3f(joint->worldTransform[12], 
                      joint->worldTransform[13], 
                      joint->worldTransform[14]);
           glVertex3f(parent->worldTransform[12], 
                      parent->worldTransform[13], 
                      parent->worldTransform[14]);
       }
   }
   glEnd();
}
```

Comment: Accepted... this is actually what I needed  I feel so dumb. I stored both local and world space just in case I needed them, but your second code block resembles what I really want. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using 20 year old legacy OpenGL? This is not a help but a malice.

Comment: Firstly thatGuy specified OpenGL 2.0, secondly no maths library was specified (Eigen? glm? User rolled?), thirdly we are talking about drawing a handful of lines here. I have zero idea whether thatGuy is using displayLists, compiled vertex arrays, vertex arrays, vbos, glBegin/glEnd, shaders, etc. GL2 is a pretty messed up spec as it is. Providing a response using glNamedBufferData probably isn't all that useful in this case.